# Pyspark Cannot resolve column name when Column does exist

Tags: pyspark

I had some Pyspark code that was working with a sample csv BLOB and then I decided to point it to a bigger dataset. This line:

```
df= df.withColumn("TransactionDate", df["TransactionDate"].cast(TimestampType()))
```

In now throwing this error:

```
AnalysisException: u'Cannot resolve column name "TransactionDate" among ("TransactionDate","Country ...
```

Clearly TransactionDate exists as a column in the dataset so why is it suddenly not working?

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok I figured it out. If you get this issue check your delimiter. In my new dataset it was "," where as in my smaller sample is was "|"

```
df = spark.read.format(file_type).options(header='true', quote='"', delimiter=",",ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace='true',inferSchema='true').load(file_location)
```